# Obtain exclusive read/write lock on a file for atomic updates

Tags: shell, shell-script, lock

I want to have a file that is used as a counter. User A will write and increment this number, while User B requests to read the file. Is it possible that User A can lock this file so no one can read or write to it until User A's write is finished?

I've looked into `flock` but can't seem to get it to work as I expect it.

```
flock -x -w 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt echo "4" >  /dev/shm/counter.txt && sleep 5
```

If there's a more appropriate way to get this atomic-like incrementing file that'd be great to hear too!

My goal is:

```
LOCK counter.txt; write to counter.txt;
```

while at the same time

```
Read counter.txt; realize it's locked so wait until that lock is finished.
```

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work as I expect it."  What __specifically__ does that mean?

Comment: I'm sure I'm using it incorrectly, but while using the code above I can use two shells and have them both edit the counter file while I thought one was locking it. So if I run that line twice on two separate shells, (each with its own number to echo), I still see the second number being written

Comment: When the first completes and releases its lock, the second runs. Isn't that the way it should work?  (In the code above, `&& sleep 5` is executed _after_ the flock releases the lock.)

Comment: Hmm intersting... So in that case it would have been too quick for my human eye to catch. Great! My next challenge is how to put multiple commands in `flock`, but I'll put that as a separate question. Thanks John!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bash's processing of the command below may be surprising:

```
flock -x -w 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt echo "4" >  /dev/shm/counter.txt && sleep 5
```

Bash first runs `flock -x -w 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt echo "4" >  /dev/shm/counter.txt` and,  if that completes successfully (releasing the lock), then it runs `sleep 5`.  Thus, the lock is not held for the 5 seconds that one may expect.

#### Aside on `&` versus `&&`

If one has two commands, `A` and `B`, then:

1. `A & B` starts `A` in the background and then starts `B` without waiting for `A` to finish.
2. `A && B` starts `A`, waits for it to complete, and then, if it completes successfully (exit code 0), starts `B`.  If `A` fails (nonzero exit code), then `B` is never run.

In sum, `&` and `&&` are two completely different list operators.

Comment: it would surprise me if in `A && B`, `A` would wait for `B` to finish.

Comment: in A && B, A is executed first. B is executed only if A executed and exited successfully. Use A; B to always execute B regardless of the execution status of A.

Answer (score 16):

File locks aren't mandatory<sup>1</sup> -- i.e., you can't lock a file so that another process *cannot* access it.  Locking a file means that if a(nother) process *checks* to see if it has been locked, it will know.

The purpose of `flock` is to do stuff like what you want, but you must then **use `flock` for each and every attempted access**.  Keep in mind those are blocking calls; from `man flock`:

> if the lock cannot be immediately acquired, flock waits until the lock is available

---

<sup>1. Which makes the feature seem useless if you are using it for, e.g., security, but that is not the purpose of file locks -- they're for synchronization, which is what you are doing. User Leo pointed out that there may be a non standardized implementation of mandatory file locking in the linux kernel ([see this discussion](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt)), based on historical parallels from other *nix operating systems.  However, this looks to be a C level interface only.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You could use "sh -c command..." to run the entire shell command, including file redirection, with the lock held.  Also, because you are using the file as a counter, you need to hold the lock continuously while you do the read and the write back.  So you would want to do something like this to increment the counter and return its new value:

```
flock --exclusive --wait 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt sh -c 'read count < /dev/shm/counter.txt ; echo $((count + 1)) > /dev/shm/counter.txt ; echo $((count + 1))'
```

Changing the plus signs to minus signs should decrement the counter:

```
flock --exclusive --wait 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt sh -c 'read count < /dev/shm/counter.txt ; echo $((count - 1)) > /dev/shm/counter.txt ; echo $((count - 1))'
```

I expect you will initialize the counter before any contention can occur, so there should be no need to worry about locking that early:

```
echo 0 > /dev/shm/counter.txt
```

I don't think you would ever need to clobber the counter value while contention could occur, but, if you ever did, you should do so thusly:

```
flock --exclusive --wait 5 /dev/shm/counter.txt sh -c 'echo 0 > /dev/shm/counter.txt'
```

I think you understand how to do the read, but I include it for completeness:

```
flock --shared /dev/shm/counter.txt cat /dev/shm/counter.txt
```

Comment: This appears to be the only answer that correctly notices that in the question, the file gets opened by the shell before flock even *runs* ...

Comment: I like this answer because it shows a way to perform the required sequence of operations while holding the lock, while the current accepted answer only says why things aren't working as expected.