# Shell script: "if file is not being used" condition

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm trying to compress a virtual machine image file through a script, but I want to be sure the file isn't being accessed. I could check if virt-manager is running, since it should be the only program accessing the image, but I don't know if there's a better way to do it. I also want the script to continue trying until the file is available to compress. I don't know how do to that either.

```
#Check if virt-manager is running
if pgrep "virt-manager" > /dev/null
then
    #re-run script until success
else
    gzip -k < /home/brady/.vms/windows10/hdd.img > /media/backup/vms/windows10/hdd.$(date +"%F.%T).img.gz
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lsof` command can tell you if a file is in use.  You can put that in a `while` loop with a `sleep` to make it check every so often.

For example:

In window 1 you can run `sleep 10000 > /tmp/x`

In window 2 run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/tmp/x

while [ -n "$(lsof "$FILE")" ]
do
  sleep 1
done

echo "File $FILE not in use"
```

Now when you press `control-C` to abort the `sleep` you'll see the "File not in use" response within a second or so.

Comment: To avoid the sleep delay could you use "until [ -z "$(lsof $FILE)" ]; do continue done echo "file not in use""

Comment: The `sleep` was deliberate to prevent a highly CPU intensive loop.  Just poll once per second rather than as quickly as possible.

Comment: Ok this should work then

Comment: `while fuser "$FILE"` is simpler, you don't need `lsof` here. And don't forget to double-quote variables.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux with the inotify tools installed, you could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
file=${1?}

# if it's a symlink, we want the real file, readlink also tells us
# if the file is accessible
file=$(readlink -e -- "$file") || exit

# start inotifywait as a coproc so we can terminate it after we're
# done:
coproc LC_ALL=C inotifywait -me close --format . -- "$file" 2>&1

# Now wait for the "Watches established." messaged. First, that allows us
# to verify inotifywait started properly, and that also avoids the race
# condition where the last file user is gone after our fuser check but
# before the watch is in place
read <&p && read <&p && [ "$REPLY" = "Watches established." ] || exit

# Now watch CLOSE events until the file has no more user:
while fuser -s "$file" && read <&p; do continue; done
printf '"%s" is no longer used, renaming it to prevent new access\n' "$file"
kill %
ret=0
if mv -- "$file" "$file.moved-away"; then
  printf 'and now compressing it\n'
  pixz -t < "$file.moved-away" > "$file.xz" || ret=$?
  mv -- "$file.moved-away" "$file" || ret=$? # move back
else
  ret=$?
fi
exit "$ret"
```

With `inotifywait`, we get notified every time a fd is closed on the file. That means we don't have to check the file so often, and can start compressing as soon as the last user has closed the file.

Note that from my tests, and contrary to what I initially feared, that also works for mmapped files as in those cases, the `CLOSE` event is not generated upon the `close()` but upon the last `munmap()` (when the file is fully released).

`fuser -s` will be a much lighter way to check a file is opened than `lsof`. `fuser` is also more likely to be available as it's a [standard UNIX command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fuser.html) (though `-s` is not a standard option, the version available on Linux does support it).

We move the file away to prevent further access before compressing it.

We use `pixz` (a multi-threaded version of `xz`, though latest version of `xz` now also support multi-threading) as it gives a much better compression ratio than gzip and more importantly, because the zipped file is randomly accessible (you can mount the content or boot it in a VM using nbdkit without having to uncompress the whole image).

Note that like `lsof`, `fuser` will not detect the file being used as a `loop` or `mtd` device backend. For loop devices, you can use `losetup -j "$file"` to check if the file is being used that way. You could for instance insert this loop after the file has been moved away:

```
while [ -n "$(losetup -j "$file.moved-away")" ]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Isn't it better to just get a read lock to the file, instead of copying it? This will reduce the time and space requirements. This avoids copying a massive file (like a 40GB backup) and avoids it taking up 2x the space. Maybe something from http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107038/133591 may be useful in this case.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, that `mv` is just a _rename_, that just changes a few bytes in a _directory file_, the file's data stays in place. Blocking processes trying to access the file may be better than making them fail trying to access it but note that locking on Linux is _advisory_, you need processes to check for locks (and qemu typically will not). mandatory locks exist but are not enabled by default, you'd need to remount the fs with the `mand` option, change the permission of the file. And then, it's the `write()`s that hang, not the `open()` which would be disruptive, not so good an idea IMO.

Comment: Does this work in bash? I'm getting ambiguous redirect on "read <&p && read <&p && [ "$REPLY" = "Watches established." ] || exit"

Comment: @BradyDean, note the `#! /bin/zsh` at the top. It uses specific zsh syntax. Recent versions of the `bash` shell have a similar feature, but the [syntax is different](/a/86372)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That is a very interesting point. I didn't though about it. And I really didn't notice it was just a rename. I though it was an entire copy, which is insane to say the least.

Comment: There's still a race condition if a new VM starts between the `fuser` check and the time the `mv` command runs. To avoid this race, you need to re-check after `mv` and move the file back if it's now open.

Comment: @Gilles, yes, or we could do the rename at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`lsof` is the right tool for this job, but by default it examines all PIDs so it's slow and CPU intensive.  Fortunately, there are some ways to speed it up.

BTW, `virt-manager` won't be the process keeping the VM's disk image-file/device open.  That'll be one of the `qemu` binaries, e.g. `qemu-system-x86_64`

If you know for a fact that only specific processes might have your file open, and you know or can get their PID(s) then you can supply them as a comma-separated list to `lsof -p`.  e.g.

```
pids=$(pgrep qemu-system | paste -sd,)
[ -n "$pids" ] && lsof -p "$pids" | grep -i filename
```

Even better than that, you can give the process name to `lsof` with the `-c` option. `-c` doesn't require an exact match of the process name, it takes a pattern (with a maximum length of 15 characters).  You can use `-c` multiple times if required on a command line.  see `man lsof` and the lsof FAQ for details.

If you use > 15 characters, you'll get an error message like this:

```
# lsof -c qemu-system-x86_64
lsof: "-c qemu-system-x86_64" length (18) > what system provides (15)
```

Anyway, an example:

```bash
# lsof -c qemu-system | grep -i FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2
qemu-syst 4770 libvirt-qemu   20u      REG                8,3 1837236224 403730954 /var/lib/libvirt/images/FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2
```

In a `while` loop, that would be something like this:

```
pname='qemu-system'
fname='FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2'

while lsof -c "$pname" | grep -qi "$fname" ; do
  sleep 0.1   # don't need to sleep for as long between checks
              # but if you're not impatient, leave it at 1 second
              # rather than 0.1.
done

echo "$fname is not in use"
```

This also works if you're using a raw partition for your VM, e.g. use `fname='/dev/sda5'` in the script fragment above.

If you're using ZFS ZVOLs or LVM LVs or similar instead of file-based images, it gets a little more complicated.  `lsof` displays the actual block device name after any symlinks are resolved, so you also have to resolve the symlinks (e.g. using `readlink -f`) and grep for that.

e.g. for ZFS, with a ZVOL called `freedos` on pool `volumes`:

```
# fname=$(readlink --n f /dev/zvol/volumes/freedos)

# echo "$fname"
/dev/zd32
```

and for LVM with an LV called `centos7`:

```
# fname=$(readlink -n -f /dev/mapper/centos7)

# echo $fname
/dev/dm-1
```

NOTE: `/dev/vg/centos7` instead of `/dev/mapper/centos7` also works.

---

I originally started writing up this `find`-based method as an answer, but realised that the `lsof -c` method is better.  I'll leave it in just to document another reasonably fast alternative.

`find -lname` is much faster and lighter on the system than running `lsof` without the `-p` PID option.

e.g.

```
# sleep 10000 > /tmp/foo &
[1] 31077
# find /proc/[0-9]*/fd/ -lname '/tmp/foo'
/proc/31077/fd/1
```

Comment: `lsof -tac "$pname" -- "$fname"`

Comment: For the find approach, you can do `find -L /proc/*/fd/* -prune -samefile "$fname" -print -quit`, but note that in the general case, that will miss a few other _open files_ that `lsof` checks like mmapped ones (I've got a problem with my answer there as well...)

Comment: Note that `pgrep qemu-system-x86_64` will also (silently this time) fail to find processes by that name as process names are limited to 15 characters on Linux. (`pgrep` also uses patterns (regexps)). If you want to search the arg list as opposed to the process name, you can use `pgrep -f`.

Comment: ah, `--`.  i was looking in the man page for a way to combine `-p` or `-c` with a filename match.  didn't think of `--`.  re: pgrep & 15 chars, that's why i used `pgrep qemu-system` rather than `qemu-system-x86_64`.  `lsof` at least warns you about the issue, `pgrep` just silently fails.

Comment: I started off using `find -L`, but decided I preferred `-lname`.

Comment: That's `-a` you want for that. `--` here is just for `$fname` starting with -/+... You'd probably want to use `-f` as well in which case `--` will be needed in any case: `lsof -tac "$pname" -f -- "$fname"`

Comment: `-L` with `-samefile` is more reliable in the general case.

Comment: Does this seem reasonable? https://gist.github.com/2bdkid/49f440e6e0a7f9e6f586cce79e67a2e3

Comment: `fuser` is the tool for this job, not `lsof`. I haven't found performance to be a problem in practice (unless you use it in an actively inefficient manner like listing all open files including sockets with reverse DNS lookup and then grep the result). But as Stéphane notes in his answer there's a small but unavoidable race condition if you only check whether the file is open.

Comment: @BradyDean looks OK except that `qemu-system-x86` is over 15 characters.  just use `pname='qemu-system'`.  BTW, for compressing qcow2 files, i'd use `qemu-img convert -c -f qcow2 -O qcow2 input.qcow2 output.qcow2` and then (if you need to replace the original with the compressed file) `mv -f output.qcow2 input.qcow2`.